# How does Postges Server know to keep a database connection open

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I wonder how does Postgres sever determine to close a DB connection, if I forgot at the Python source code side.

Does the Postgres server send a ping to the source code? From my understanding, this is not possible.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with things they don't relate to. MySQL has nothing to do with Postgres and/or Python in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL indeed does something like that, although it is not a ping.

PostgreSQL uses a TCP feature called *keepalive*. Once enabled for a socket, the operating system kernel will regularly send *keepalive messages* to the other party (the *peer*), and if it doesn't get an answer after a couple of tries, it closes the connection.

The default timeouts for keepalive are pretty long, in the vicinity of two hours. You can configure the settings in PostgreSQL, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#guc-tcp-keepalives-idle) for details.

The default values and possible values vary according to the operating system used.

There is a similar feature available for the client side, but it is less useful and not enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

When your script quits your connection will close and the server will clean it up accordingly. Likewise, it's often the case in garbage collected languages like Python that when you stop using the connection and it falls out of scope it will be closed and cleaned up.

It is possible to write code that never releases these resources properly, that just perpetually creates new handles, something that can be problematic if you don't have something server-side that handles killing these after some period of idle time. Postgres doesn't do this by default, though it can be configured to, but MySQL does.

In short Postgres will keep a database connection open until you kill it either explicitly, such as via a `close` call, or implicitly, such as the handle falling out of scope and being deleted by the garbage collector.

Comment: I think that the question is more about one end of the connection dying without properly closing the connection.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe A reasonable interpretation as well.